# Setup Managed Backup failure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to setup Managed Backup (in Azure SQL) using SQLServer  2014 (Ent 64bit) and  it is failing.

I have the credential created with Identity as the Storage account name and Password set with current Access key, I've tried both keys as well.

When I run through the GUI to Enable managed backup, set the retention period, add the SQL credential (which updates the Storage URL) and I press OK, I get the follow error message back:
Alter failed for

> SmartAdmin 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ObjectKeyBase'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> Failed to access the storage URL 'https://[storageaccountname].blob.core.windows.net/' using credential 'MyCredName'. 
>   Provide a valid SQL Credential for the storage URL. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 45207)

I downloaded Azure Storage Explorer from codeplex to test connection and it works, I can browse, upload, delete from my local machine.

I tried this from one of our on prem servers as well and same error.  What am I missing?

Comment: Error message is clear,can you double check your credential

Comment: That was my thought too, which is why I am thinking I am missing something super simple.  The credential has been deleted and recreated numerous times.  I've tried key 1 and key 2, still no dice.   I validated it authenticates and provides access to the URL by using Azure Storage Explorer.

Comment: Is the URL correct? Don't you need to provide the container as well? I don't know for sure, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: URL is correct, yes.  I did try the container, however that is not permitted. 
Specifying a container name is not allowed as part of the URL configuration. Input an URL for the storage account without the container, such as: 'https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/'.

Answer (score 1):

Issue identified.  The network admin didn't have the separate Azure domain environments trusted, although he said that he did.  I tried this and failed in our SQL DEV environment/domain in Azure, which isn't trusted.  I then, for sake of troubleshooting and communicating to the powers to be, tried it from our SQL QA environment/domain in Azure and it worked flawlessly!  The network admin compared the two environments and found the issue. Network issue after all.